# How to recover game data from a smashed phone?

Tags: applications

Hey guys so it happens my Dad has been having a huff lately because he smashed his phone screen and he can't remember the password to his gmail account however he has months of game data stored on the device snd he's angry because he doesn't want to start again lol any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Does the device itself have a passcode? Either way, the device is probably accessible through USB. Get [ADB](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=48915118), plug the device into a computer, and using ADB (hopefully USB debugging was enabled before your dad sent it to hell) first type `adb devices` to make sure your computer sees the phone. If you're successful, you'll see your phone get listed on the screen. Then type `adb backup -all -f C:\Backups\Android.ab` This will create an Android backup file. You'll need to get an android backup extractor in order to retrieve your data files (like [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2011811). Google is your frienemy...;) Hopefully, this will resolve your problem. Good luck!